# Google Charts won't align on top

Tags: javascript, html, css, charts

I've tried all the answers I could find here but I'm lost. I'm making a simple flask app to query a database and present information to my client. I'd like to use google charts but when I output a simple chart it shows up far down the page. I want it to align in the center at the top how can I achieve this without linking to external css? I've tried everything I could find so here is a cleaned up version of my html.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});
   google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
 function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
   data.addColumn('string', 'Patients');
   data.addColumn('number', 'Date');
   data.addRows([
     ['05/29', 26],
     ['05/30', 16],
     ['06/01', 32],
     ['06/02', 15],
     ['06/03', 23],
     ['06/04', 6],
     ['06/05', 16],
     ['06/06', 21],
     ['06/08', 29],
     ['06/09', 21],
     ['06/10', 19],
     ['06/11', 14],
     ['06/12', 14],
     ['06/13', 10],
     ['06/15', 17],
     ['06/16', 17],
     ['06/17', 12],
     ['06/18', 9],
     ['06/19', 9],
     ['06/20', 9],
     ['06/22', 8],
     ['06/23', 16],
     ['06/24', 9],
     ['06/25', 8],
     ['06/26', 6],
     ['06/27', 6],
     ['06/29', 2],
     ['06/30', 1],
     ['07/01', 1],
     ['07/02', 1],
     ['07/06', 9],
     ['07/07', 10],
     ['07/08', 8],
     ['07/09', 8],
     ['07/10', 11],
     ['07/11', 8],
     ['07/13', 7],
     ['07/14', 9],
     ['07/15', 8],
     ['07/16', 7],
     ['07/17', 8],
     ['07/18', 3],
     ['07/20', 8],
     ['07/21', 6],
     ['07/22', 1],
     ['07/23', 2],
     ['07/24', 6],
     ['07/25', 7],
     ['07/27', 4],
     ['07/28', 2],
     ['07/29', 3],
     ['07/30', 1],
     ['07/31', 5],
     ['08/01', 7],
     ['08/03', 6],
     ['08/04', 7],
     ['08/05', 7],
     ['08/06', 7],
     ['08/07', 3],
     ['08/08', 7],
     ['08/10', 8],
     ['08/11', 5],
     ['08/12', 3],
     ['08/13', 4],
     ['08/14', 5],
     ['08/15', 6],
     ['08/17', 5],
     ['08/18', 3],
     ['08/19', 4],
     ['08/20', 3],
     ['08/21', 3],
     ['08/22', 4],
     ['08/24', 3],
     ['08/25', 4],
     ['08/26', 5],
     ['08/27', 5],
     ['08/28', 6],
     ['08/29', 5],
     ['09/01', 4],
     ['09/02', 3],
     ['09/03', 1],
     ['09/04', 4],
     ['09/05', 3],
     ['09/07', 1],
     ['09/08', 2],
     ['09/09', 2],
     ['09/11', 2],
     ['09/12', 2],
     ['09/14', 5],
     ['09/15', 3],
     ['09/16', 2],
     ['09/17', 4],
     ['09/18', 6],
     ['09/19', 1],
     ['09/21', 2],
     ['09/22', 3],
     ['09/23', 3],
     ['09/24', 6],
     ['09/25', 4],
     ['09/26', 3],
     ['09/28', 7],
     ['09/29', 4],
     ['09/30', 5],
     ['10/01', 3],
     ['10/02', 2],
     ['10/03', 2],
     ['10/05', 4],
     ['10/06', 4],
     ['10/07', 5],
     ['10/08', 4],
     ['10/09', 5],
     ['10/10', 2],
     ['10/12', 2],
     ['10/13', 3],
     ['10/14', 3],
     ['10/15', 3],
     ['10/16', 4],
     ['10/17', 5],
     ['10/19', 3],
     ['10/20', 3],
     ['10/21', 3],
     ['10/22', 3],
     ['10/23', 7],
     ['10/24', 1],
     ['10/26', 4],
     ['10/27', 3],
     ['10/28', 4],
     ['10/29', 1],
     ['10/30', 2],
     ['11/02', 5],
     ['11/03', 1],
     ['11/04', 5],
     ['11/05', 6],
     ['11/06', 3],
     ['11/09', 7],
     ['11/10', 4],
     ['11/12', 4],
     ['11/13', 3],
     ['11/14', 2],
     ['11/16', 8],
     ['11/17', 1],
     ['11/18', 4],
     ['11/19', 7],
     ['11/20', 3],
     ['11/21', 4],
     ['11/23', 5],
   ]);
   var options = {'title':'Future appointment projections',
       'width':750,
       'height':4000};
var chart = new     google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(data, options);  }
</script>
</head>
<body><div id="chart_div"></div></body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the chart options like so:

```
var options = {'title':'Future appointment projections',
'width': 750,
'height': 4000,
'chartArea': {'height': '96%'},
'legend': {'position': 'bottom'}
};
```

Thanks to Approv3d of reddit for the assist.